# Sublime Text 2 plugin for REBOL

Tags: ide, editor, rebol

Are there any up to date REBOL plugins for Sublime Text 2?  I'm using a TextMate one from http://www.ross-gill.com/page/TextMate_and_REBOL, but it's pretty old.  Also, for learning REBOL/Red what's a good interactive, learning environment?

Comment: One of the tricks up Red/Rebol's sleeve is being "literate" enough you don't need an IDE.  But it's still one of those "you debug it with print statements" kind of languages at the moment.  There've been a few interactive tutorial efforts ([Google Cache of one of them](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3P7Y-V1w0MsJ:www.rebol.net/wiki/Interactive_tutorial_script&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1)), but right now the best bet is to [come chat with RebolBot](http://stackapps.com/questions/3960/rebolbot-a-chat-bot-for-the-chat-rooms).  :-)

Comment: I agree with HostileFork.  If you play around with RebolBot on the Rebol/Red Stack Overflow Chat, there's almost always an experienced Reboler on there that is more than happy to help out with any questions you might have!

Comment: trouble is .. there's a 20 point barrier to chatting with rebolbot .. try asking a Rebol question as well

Answer (score 1):

I use SciTe  (http://www.scintilla.org), it's ready for Rebol syntax, and all configuration files are very simple text files.

Comment: The actual Rebol lexer is in C(++ - not sure).

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the TextMate bundle is here: https://github.com/rgchris/rebol-tmbundle I'd welcome contributions.

Not certain why age is a problem when the highlighter works (and has been tested to work with Sublime Text). Could you elaborate on what has broken over time?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new one, based on rgchris' work, which is compatible with Sublime Text 3:

[rebol-red-sublime](https://github.com/onetom/rebol-red-sublime)

I'm using it with success.